# Symfony 2 - Generate PDF with Knp-Snappy output HTML

Tags: symfony, pdf, twig

I have a problem with Knp-Snappy bundle in my Symfony2 project.
I followed this link to install it : http://knpbundles.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle.
Whenever I click on the link to generate a PDF from the Twig view, it renders me only the HTML page and doesn't generate the PDF.

Here's the print part of my Controller.

```
    $html = $this->renderView('PACESColleBundle:Classement:generationPDF.html.twig', array(
        "passercolles" => $passercolles,
        "colle" => $colle,
        "moyenne" => $moyenne,
        "mediane" => $mediane,
        "effectif" => $effectif,
        "note100" => $note100
    ));

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="classement.pdf"'
        )

    );
```

Comment: You should remove the noise from your example code and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that something in your view produces a notice / warning, headers will be sent and at that point is too late to send a PDF response.

Remove the view generation and just pass a static HTML to test PDF generation itself, i.e.:

```
$html = "Just a sample text to produce the PDF";

return new Response(
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="classement.pdf"'
    )
);
```

Also please carefully check the application logs in /app/logs/*.log.